# How to sort out discrete cells on the cell text color

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, text, colors

[image]

[image]

The first image above is the original situation, while the next image is the result after vba sorting code.

Question: I have tried code below, but cant figure out how to make these work. I wish to reedit these vba code to make the result as the picture shown above.

```
        Dim gp_cell_1 As Range
        Dim gp_cell_2 As Range
        Set gp_cell_1 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 5, y + 1))
        Set gp_cell_2 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 3), ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 5, y + 3))

        Set gp_cell = Application.Union(gp_cell_1, gp_cell_2)

        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim rngSort As Range

        Set sht = ActiveSheet

        sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        sht.Sort.SortFields.Add(gp_cell, _
            xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , _
            xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        With sht.Sort
            .SetRange gp_cell
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an exercise in range definition. Therefore you need a really good method of defining rows and columns. In the code below I use an enumeration for this purpose which must be at the top of the module, before any procedures. Review the values and adjust them to what you need before you run the code. Also set the name of the tab to the one present in your workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Par                        ' Definition of parameters
                                ' you can change any of the values below

    ParFirstDataRow = 1         ' location of original data
    ParNumRows = 5              ' number of rows

    ParFirstClm = 5             ' 5 = column E, location of original data
    ParSecondClm = 7            ' 7 = column G, location of original data
    ParTempClm = 10             ' Allow macro to use this column temporarily
End Enum

Sub MergeAndSort()
    ' Variatus @STO 19 Jan 2020

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' change tab name to suit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Ws
        ' copy first range to temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParFirstClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParFirstClm))
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, ParTempClm)

        ' copy second range to temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParSecondClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParSecondClm))
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(ParNumRows + 1, ParTempClm)

        ' define the combined range to sort
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells(ParNumRows * 2, ParTempClm))

        With .Sort
            With .SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Rng.Cells(1), _
                          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                          Order:=xlAscending, _
                          DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            End With
            .SetRange Rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        ' move first range from temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParTempClm))
        Rng.Cut Destination:=.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParFirstClm)

        ' move second range from temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParNumRows + 1, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells((ParNumRows * 2), ParTempClm))
        Rng.Cut Destination:=.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParSecondClm)
    End With

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This code will first merge the two ranges into a single column, sort that column, and then transport the top half of the sorted column back to the first location and the rest to the second.

Comment: Thank you!! I can make it right now. Learn a lot with this trick from you !

Answer (score 0):

I post the exact answer here

```
    ParFirstDataRow = x + 1       ' location of original data
    ParNumRows = 5                ' number of rows
    ParFirstClm = y + 1           ' column , location of original data
    ParSecondClm = y + 3          ' column , location of original data
    ParTempClm = 38 

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet          ' change tab name to suit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Ws
        ' copy first range to temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParFirstClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParFirstClm))
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm)

        ' copy second range to temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParSecondClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParSecondClm))
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(ParNumRows + ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm)

        ' define the combined range to sort
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells(ParNumRows * 2 + ParFirstDataRow - 1, ParTempClm))

        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(Rng, _
         xlSortOnFontColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
         .SetRange Rng
         .Header = xlNo
         .MatchCase = False
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply
        End With


        ' move first range from temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells(ParFirstDataRow + ParNumRows - 1, ParTempClm))
        Rng.Cut Destination:=.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParFirstClm)

        ' move second range from temporary column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(ParNumRows + ParFirstDataRow, ParTempClm), _
                         .Cells((ParNumRows * 2 + ParFirstDataRow - 1), ParTempClm))
        Rng.Cut Destination:=.Cells(ParFirstDataRow, ParSecondClm)
    End With

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
```

Comment: You have *Set Ws = ActiveSheet*. Of course, the ActiveSheet is always in the ActiveWorkbook. Therefore *Ws* equals "ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet". Your addressing this same sheet as "ActiveSheet" and then "ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet" makes no sense within the *With Ws* statement. I suggest you keep the structure of the code as I made it and just add your extra specifications to the *.Add Key* part of the code. Frankly, I doubt that your specs work. Look up "Sortkey.add" in MSDN. Your code leaves unclear which value is assigned to which property. My code leaves colours where they were.